# Hibernate @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I started to play around with Hibernate since yesterday and came up with the following example of one-to-many relationship example, but I am not sure if I am doing right and I have no one around me knowing Hibernate.  Please take a quick look at it, then maybe point out anything wrong.

My goal is to use a one-to-many relationship with annotations to perform basic Insert and Update.

The Entity classes are from [here](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html).

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>(0);

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String studentName, Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentPhoneNumbers = studentPhoneNumbers;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    public long getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
    public Set<Phone> getStudentPhoneNumbers() {
        return this.studentPhoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setStudentPhoneNumbers(Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers) {
        this.studentPhoneNumbers = studentPhoneNumbers;
    }
//I added in this method for updating
    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.studentPhoneNumbers.add(phone);
    }

}
```

**Phone**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE")
public class Phone {

    private long phoneId;
    private String phoneType;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Phone() {
    }

    public Phone(String phoneType, String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PHONE_ID")
    public long getPhoneId() {
        return this.phoneId;
    }

    public void setPhoneId(long phoneId) {
        this.phoneId = phoneId;
    }

    @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE", nullable = false, length=10)
    public String getPhoneType() {
        return this.phoneType;
    }

    public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
    }

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length=15)
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

**`CreateMain`: create the entry in `STUDENT`, `STUDENT_PHONE` and `PHONE` tables**

```
public class CreateMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            Set<Phone> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>();
            phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("house", "32354353"));
            phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("mobile", "9889343423"));

            Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers);
            session.save(student);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**`UpdateMain`: Insert a new PHONE entry for the entry created in `CreateMain`**

```
public class UpdateMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testupd = "Eswar";
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();            
            Query queryResult =  session.createQuery("from Student");  
            List allStudents =  queryResult.list();  
            for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++) {  
                    Student student = (Student) allStudents.get(i);  
                    if(student.getStudentName().compareTo(testupd)==0) {
                        student.addPhone(new Phone("test","12345678"));
                        session.update(student); 
                    }
            }  
            session.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**`DeleteMain`: delete the entry**

```
public class UpdateMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testupd = "Eswar";
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();            
            Query queryResult =  session.createQuery("from Student");  
            List allStudents =  queryResult.list();  
            for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++) {  
                    Student student = (Student) allStudents.get(i);  
                    if(student.getStudentName().compareTo(testupd)==0) {
                        student.addPhone(new Phone("test","12345678"));
                        session.update(student); 
                    }
            }  
            session.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just 3 little remarks because it really looks good already.

- You want the setters of the id's to be private. They are generated
  values by Hibernate and other classes shouldn't mess with them.
- Also for the default constructors of `Student` and `Phone`, Hibernate
  needs only default package visibility. So best to remove the public
  access modifiers in your default constructors.
- I would also create a `StudentDao` class instead of the 3 *Main classes. And if you like, you can use Spring Transaction annotations to reduce the transaction boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

How well does your code work? I haven't tested it, but I see some things that may cause the program to behave strangely. Overall, it's still OK though.

- Consider placing the annotations (`@Column`, `@Id`, ...) on the fields rather than the accessors. I know the debate is still open, but I think the improved readability of your class (column definitions are a lot closer to each other) more than compensate any downside it could have (except if you *need* it of course).
- From a purely relational point of view, you're missing a column in your "Phone" entity. You need both a `technical id` (primary key) and the `ID` of the student whom it belongs to. Currently, you're using the "phoneId" column as a foreign key (`inverseJoinColumns = phone_id`) and a primary key (with a generated value at that!) I don't see how it can work well. This is your biggest problem currently.
- Unless your use case requires the opposite, you should create the "Many" entity and set its "One" entity. In your case, create a phone, set its student and save it. You can't do that currently because you don't have a "Student" attribute in the "Phone" entity. You should add it. The reason for that is that every time you want to ass a phone to a student, you need the entire collection (so you can add something to it). Hibernate will fetch it from the database, which can be slow if your collection is big, even though you don't actually need the collection. In some cases (if you're using the entity outside a transaction and the collection is lazily loaded) it could even fail!